# A trigonometry equation problem

Tags: trigonometry

Let $a,b \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, satisfying
$$
\frac{1-\cos{2a}}{1+\sin{a}}+\frac{1+\cos{2a}}{1+\cos{b}}=\frac{1-\cos{(2a+2b)}}{1+\sin{(a+2b)}}
$$
Prove that:
$$
a+b=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you try to add the fractions on the left-hand side, or use the trigonometric addition formulas on the right-hand side?

Comment: Should the denominator on the right be $1+\sin(\mathbf{2}a+2b)$?

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Why do you think it's true?

Comment: @Zander I've checked in Mathematica, this is true.

Comment: It is true, I have used mathematica to solve it, take $\tan{a/2}$ and $\tan{b/2}$ as variables, and the result is true, but I need some easier way to solve it

Comment: @daniel:fix $a$, the uniqueness of $b$ remain unknown

Comment: @daniel both are shown below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following calculations, show the non-uniqueness of the statement to be proven and therefore that the proposition is not true, when we forget the restriction $a,b \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ (Thanks to Christian). Then $a+b=\frac\pi2$ is a sufficient, but not a necessary condition for $f(a,b) = 0$, because of the existence of other zeros. $f(a,b)$ can be splitted in at least $3$ factors and so $f(a,b)=0$ implies $\frac12\left(a+b-\frac\pi 2\right)=\pi n$ and/or $\frac12(a-\frac\pi2)=\pi m$, plus some more weird solutions, where a nice general expression is currently lacking (or might not exist), although some particular values can be specified. Here it is:

When you plot 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(a,b)&=&(1+\cos(b))(1+\sin(a+2b))(1-\cos 2a)\\
&+&(1+\sin a)(1+\sin(a+2b))(1+\cos2a)\\
&-&(1+\cos(b))(1+\sin a)(1-\cos(2a+2b))=0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
you'll clearly see the $a+b=\frac{\pi}{2}$-line, among other possible solutions (some of them are briefly discussed below in the **EDIT**):

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

[W|A](http://tinyurl.com/bq83bly) helped to expand it
to 
$$
\sin(\frac a2-\frac\pi4) \color{red}{\sin(\frac a2+\frac b2-\frac\pi 4)} 
\biggr\{
\sin(a-\frac52 b)+3 \sin(a-\frac b2)+3 \sin(a+\frac b2)\\+6 \sin(a+\frac32 b)-\sin(3 a+\frac32 b)+2 \sin(a+\frac52 b)-2 \cos(2 a-\frac b2)\\ -\cos(2 a+\frac b2)-3 \cos(2 a+\frac32 b)+7 \cos(\frac b2)+2 \cos(\frac32 b)+\cos(\frac52 b)
\biggr\}=0 \tag{*}
$$
and then it is obvious, that $\frac12\left(a+b-\frac\pi 2\right)=\pi n$ solves this equation, as well as $\frac12(a-\pi/2)=\pi m$ does. Other solutions are visible, but not obvious.

**EDIT** [Wolfram](http://tinyurl.com/cuald4n) kindly provides some more
particular roots of the $\{\cdots\}$-part of $(*)$ like
$$
a=2\pi c_1+\pi \; \;, b=-4\left(\pi c_2+\tan^{-1}(x_k)\right),
$$
where

- $x_{0,1}=1\pm\sqrt{2}\;$ (roots of $x^2-2x-1\;$) or
- $x_{2,3,4,5}$, one of [$4$ real roots of $x^8-8 x^7-20 x^6-8 x^5+22 x^4+8x^3-20 x^2+8 x+1$](http://tinyurl.com/cp4q3bx).

---

The converse of the statement is much easier to proof:
Substitute $b=\pi/2-a$ to get:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1-\cos{2a}}{1+\sin{a}}+\frac{1+\cos{2a}}{1+\cos({\frac\pi2-a})}
&=&\frac{1-\cos{(2a+\pi-2a)}}{1+\sin{(a+\pi-2a)}}\\
&=&\frac{1-\cos{(\pi)}}{1+\sin{(\pi-a)}}\\
\frac{1-\cos{2a}}{1+\sin{a}}+\frac{1+\cos{2a}}{1+\sin a}&=&\frac{2}{1+\sin{a}}\\
\frac{2}{1+\sin{a}}&=&\frac{2}{1+\sin{a}}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: @daniel ask WA, screenshot and upload (there is a small picture above the edit field)...

Comment: @daniel thank you very much for caring so much. I took up your thoughts about $\frac12\left(a+b-\frac\pi 2\right)=\pi n$, $\frac12(a-\pi/2)=\pi m$ and updated the figure. I'm not sure how to *relate this back to the original question*. Any concrete ideas for that? Maybe it's the heavy use of Wolfram. Some people might not like it. I do, I love it. Thanks again...

Comment: Maybe add at the beginning: "The OP asks for proof that ...etc. The following calculations show that the proposition is in general not true. a+b=pi/2 is a sufficient but not a necessary condition for f(a,b) = 0, because of the existence of other zeros. The implication is therefore of the form f(a,b)=0 implies A and/or B and/or C...in which A,B,C,... are zeros of the equation." I think this was a neat solution, because most people probably saw the problem of non-uniqueness, but showing it clearly was another matter.

Comment: The picture shows that the original statement is in fact **true**. Note that the variables $a$ and $b$ were from the beginning restricted to the interval $\ \bigl]0,{\pi\over2}\bigr[\ $.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, well spotted, my brain must have been still in the warm up phase, when I first read the question and I never got back that far. I edited it to take that into account...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I also used wolfram to solve it by turning $\tan{\frac{a}{2}},\tan{\frac{b}{2}}$ into variables, which also require much calculation. Your answer gave me another method to deal with this problem.

Comment: @Golbez You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Let, without loss of generality, $a=\frac{\pi}{2}-(b-c)$,

then by using the fact that you can suck up $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (and thereby change $\sin$ to $\cos$) as well as $\pi$ (and thereby change a sign of the trigonometric function) you can get rid of all $\pi$'s and $a$'s:

$$
\frac{1-\cos{2a}}{1+\sin{a}}+\frac{1+\cos{2a}}{1+\cos{b}}=\frac{1-\cos{(2a+2b)}}{1+\sin{(a+2b)}}
$$

$$\Longrightarrow$$

$$
\frac{1+\cos{(2(b-c))}}{1+\cos{(b-c)}}+\frac{1-\cos{(2(b-c))}}{1+\cos{b}}=\frac{1+\cos{(2c)}}{1+\cos{(b+c)}}
$$

Now it is acutally clear that $a+b=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a solution, because if you plug in $c=0$, all three denomiators become $1+\cos{(b)}$ and the equation reads $2=2$.

If you want to go futher you can use $$\cos ( b \pm c ) = \cos (b)  \cos (c) \mp \sin (b)  \sin (c)$$ to isolate the two trigonometric functions of $c$, substitue $t=\tan{\frac{c}{2}}$ to get polynomial expression in $t$, put everything on one equal denominator and solve the thing. This will amount to $t=\tan{(0)}=0$.